# C++ method wrapping Objective-C: how to add value to variable?

Tags: c++, objective-c, webkit, node-webkit

OK this is total noob question:

I have simple C++ method:

```
 void Tray::IconPos(const std::string& iconpos) {
   NSRect rect = [[[status_item_ view] window] frame];
   iconpos = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y];
 }
```

where I want `std::string& iconpos` to gain this: `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y]` value.

How do I do that here?

Ninja is giving me:

```
tray_mac.mm:72:11: error: no viable overloaded '='
iconpos = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y];
~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are going to convert `NSRect` to `NSString` you probably want `NSStringFromRect`.

However, if you want to format it yourself, into a `std::string`, then why convert it to a `NSString` just to convert it again to a `std::string`?

Second, you are trying to assign to `iconpos` which is a reference to a const std::string.  You just can't do that.

If you want to convert from `NSString` to a `std::string` you will need to go through a regular C string, with the `NSString` method `cStringUsingEncoding:`.

However, no matter what you do, you can't assign to `iconpos` because it is a reference to a constant object.

Answer (score 0):

Your should try something like this:

```
iconpos = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y] UTF8String];
```

Comment: still the same error: :-(
`../../content/nw/src/api/tray/tray_mac.mm:72:11: error: no viable overloaded '='
  iconpos = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y] UTF8String];
  ~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: How about this:
`iconpos.assign([[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y] UTF8String]);` ?

Comment: `../../content/nw/src/api/tray/tray_mac.mm:73:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'assign'
  iconpos.assign([[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y] UTF8String]);
  ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:927:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>'), but method is not marked const
      assign(const _CharT* __s)
      ^
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`

Comment: As Jody Hagins pointed out, you are trying to assign to a const reference. Remove the 'const' from the header declaration.